# Elastic image effect

Tags: android, image

How to give elastic effects to images that is when the image is clicked it gets zoomed up and when the close button is pressed it regains its original size?

Comment: Which version of Android are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

can use `ScaleGestureDetector` on android which keeps handle on Zoom factor, see example http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

see **GestureDetectors** here your main tool will be `ScaleFactor`

On image click increase Scalefactor value and on pressing back button make `ScaleFactor=1`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `WebView` to make use of `ZoomControls`: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/using-webview-as-a-image-zoom-view-control/